# Свойство super и this в Node.js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите плиз. В данном коде emit не метод суперкласса? Я имею ввиду почему this.emit ,а не super.emit.Гугл ничего путного не подсказал.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

let eventName = 'greet'

class User extends EventEmitter {
  sayHi(data) {
    this.emit(eventName, data)
  }
}

let user = new User()
// добавляем к объекту user обработку события "greet"
user.on(eventName, function (data) {
  console.log(data)
})

user.sayHi('Мне нужна твоя одежда...')
```

Comment: Если this это наследник super, то нет разницы, всё равно по цепочке прототипов этот метод будет найден в super. Вызывая методы от наследника, имеем возможность их переопределять в нём. Да и просто по смыслу он и так является расширенным предком.

Comment: Получается без this можно обойтись,поскольку он находится в теле класса?А super необходимо только когда метод в constructor находится(переопределяется конструктором)?Т.е. не в prototype.Выходит так?

Comment: Без `this` никак не обойтись, js отличается в этом например от C#. А `super` нужен, чтобы взять метод предка, когда такой же метод имеется у потомка. Если в переопределённом методе использовать `this`, то будет зацикленная ссылка на этот же метод, а при `super` будет взят метод предка с тем же названием. В потомке в конструкторе используют `super()` чтобы вызвать конструктор предка, который должен отработать раньше конструктора потомка.

Comment: Все правильно.Я сам запутался. Спасибо!!